# Enable .htaccess On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Apache-2.4.41

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem when moving my website to VULTR VPS - Ubuntu 20.04LTS with Apache - 2.4.41

I'm using Opencart for my website and my problem is whenever I move .htaccess file to the new hosting, the website will display 500 error code.

So I tried to enable rewrite mod.

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

restart the server

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Then I add some code to the following config files
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also change the code of apache2.conf file in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

From

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also restart the server to make sure it takes effect.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Unfortunately, I got no luck with it. Whenever I move the .HTACCESS file to VULTR. The website still display 500 error code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24ajl.png)

Here is the code inside my .HTACCESS file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

    # Prevent Directoy listing
    Options -Indexes
    
    # Prevent Direct Access to files
    <FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
     Require all denied
    ## For apache 2.2 and older, replace "Require all denied" with these two lines :
    # Order deny,allow
    # Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>
    
    # SEO URL Settings
    RewriteEngine On
    # If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/
    
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
    RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
    RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Could you please help me with this issue? I really appreciate your help

Comment: Are you sure the 500 error is the result of `.htaccess` and not something else? There should be a more specific reason for the error located in `/var/log/apache2`. Is the filename in all caps or lowercase?

Comment: This is what I got in /var/log/apache2/error.log. I'm pretty sure 500 error code is caused by .htaccess file ( the .htaccess file in lowercase). If I rename the .htacess to .htacess.txt, I can access the homepage of website. However, without .htacess file, I can't access other pages such as https://www.website/product , https://www.website/category . As I understand, the .htacess file in Opencart will allow me to use friendly url for website.

Comment: The error is pointing to an issue in your mod_security configuration. You may want to check that everything there is properly configured.

Comment: As I find out the mod security may be too strict, I tried to switch OFF security ID 210492 in plesk but again I got no luck. There is no more error code related to ModSecurity. I also turn off the fire wall to see if it can change something, but still got no luck.

Comment: @matigo "The error is pointing to an issue in your mod_security configuration." - Where was this stated?

Comment: @MrWhite looks like the comment containing the error has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Updated: Problem Solved. The problem occurs because FollowSymlinks not allowed in plesk

So I go to plesk >> website domain >> Apache & Nginx Setting >> disable Restrict the ability to follow symbolic links

Comment: As an alternative to `FollowSymLinks` you may be able to use (the more restrictive) `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` instead.